# What is the difference between a click2compute server and a VM server?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have always seen c2c servers like : `vc2cptm3245768j`  , `vc2cptk3245769g`  etc . I have also seen vm servers like : `vlptm1ggoi987`, `vlptk1ggoi988` .
I know that the c2c servers are like IAAS provided servers running in cloud , where as the vm servers are probably virtual servers running on top of physical servers .

But , can someone please explain the difference between the both in a palatable fashion for me ?I still keep getting confused between the two .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where as the vm servers are probably virtual servers running on top of physical servers .

"Cloud" and "IAAS" **is** just a lot of virtual servers running on top of physical servers.

It seems that "Click2compute" is a **brand name** of one specific "cloud" VM-hosting service, apparently run internally by some company named Fidelity for use by its employees.

From what little public documentation is available, it seems to be functionally the same thing as any other "cloud" service – just one company's own take on building a system that automatically deploys VMs across a cluster in a user-friendly way, likely with VM templates tailored to its own needs. (It all sounds like it's a frontend for Openstack, really.)